# Where does the function $f(z) = z \cdot Re(z) + \bar{z} \cdot Im(z) +\bar{z}$ have a complex derivative? Compute the derivative wherever it exists.

Tags: complex-analysis, multivariable-calculus

> Where does the function $f(z) = z \cdot Re(z) + \bar{z} \cdot Im(z)
> +\bar{z}$ have a complex derivative? Compute the derivative wherever it exists.

$$f(z) = z \cdot Re(z) + \bar{z} \cdot Im(z) + \bar{z} = (x+iy) \cdot x +  (x-iy) \cdot y + (x-iy) = (x^2 +xy +x) + i(xy -y^2 -y)$$

$$u(x,y) = x^2 +xy +x \rightarrow u_x = 2x + y + 1 \text{ and } u_y = x$$

$$v(x,y) = xy -y^2 -y \rightarrow v_x = y \text{ and } v_y = x - 2y - 1$$

Clearly all the partial derivatives are continuous.

Satisfying Cauchy Riemann Equations we get,

$$u_x = v_y \rightarrow x+3y+2 = 0 \text{ and } u_y = - v_x \rightarrow x = - y$$

Hence, we get,

$$ -y + 3y + 2 =0  \rightarrow y =-1 \rightarrow  x = 1$$

Since the partial derivatives of $u$ and $v$ are continuous at this point and also exist in its neighbourhood, we have that $f(z)$ has a complex derivative at only $(1,-1) $ or $1 - i$

And, $$ u_x(1,-1) = 2 \text{ and } v_x(1,-1) = -1$$

So, the required derivative is: $ f'(1-i) = 2 - i$

Is my answer/solution correct?

Comment: Yes it checks out

Comment: Yes, except one tiny mistake: The partial derivatives need to exist *and* be continuous in a neighborhood, not just exist in a neighborhood and be continuous in a single point.

Comment: @Vercassivelaunos in my textbook it says continuity at the point is sufficient, existence in a neighbourhood is necessary

Comment: The latter is certainly false. The function $z\mapsto z^2$ if both real and imaginary part of $z$ are rational and $z\mapsto0$ otherwise has no partial derivatives at rational coordinates, but is complex differentiable at $0$. And I'm pretty sure the former is false as well, though I'm struggling to find a counterexample. There's a theorem that a function is real differentiable if its partial derivatives exist and are continuous in a neighborhood. That's what you really need for the Cauchy-Riemann equations to be of use, continuity of the partials is just a proxy for it.

Comment: I've never seen a stronger version of the type "if all partials exist in a neighborhood and are continuous at a point, then the function is real differentiable at the point".